# CAML query incorrectly returns all items

Tags: development, caml

I am querying a list with this CAML Query:

```
var camlQuery = @"<Query>
                        <Where>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                            <Value Type='Text'>MP Test</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        </Where>
                    </Query>";
return _sharepoint.GetListItems(_masterListName, camlQuery);
```

Here is the code for `GetListItems`:

```
using (_clientContext = new ClientContext(Url))
{
    _clientContext.Credentials = _credentials;
    var web = _clientContext.Web;

    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    _clientContext.Load(list.Fields);

    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = camlString;
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    _clientContext.Load(listItems);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    return listItems;
}
```

There is only 1 item on the list with the title `MP Test`, yet when I run this code I keep getting 38 entries in the `listItems` variable. I can see that the titles of those items are definitely not `MP Test`.. Wh am I getting these? Have I not sent off the query correctly?

I tried removing the `Query` tags as per [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85580/caml-query-for-sharepoint-list-not-working) but with the same result.

Also tried adding `"`s around `MP Test` - same results.

Appreciate any guidance on this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `View` as the root element in the CAML query. It should be:

```
var camlQuery = @"<View>
                  <Query>
                    <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>MP Test</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
                </View>";
```